# How to get a flattened list back to breezejs through webapi2?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I have been struggling with this for a week now. I have a table of **Person** and **Company** in the DB. However, there is also a joiner Table of **CompanyPerson** which has some extra properties like *IsPrimaryPerson*. Great. Works and all that stuff if I load each thing on it's own into breezejs.

So the problem is that I want to create a list of Persons, but flattened with Companies, like a left outer join, so that I also get each person and company on one line and also include those who do not have a company.

This linq statement in C# gives me that list, I used linqPad to get it working. It's a left outer join sql equivlant.

```
  from p in Person
    join cp in CompanyPerson
     on p.Id equals cp.PersonId
     into companyPersonGroups
     from cp in companyPersonGroups.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        Person = p,
        CompanyPerson = cp,
        Company = cp.Company
        }
```

Great. However what I don't know, is how to get a list like this back to breezejs via the webapi2. Issue one is that the linq returns an anonymnous object. I've tried creating like a ContactPerson object and having properties for Person and Company but I don't know how to get back to breeze since it's not part of the metadata.

Controller, this doesn't work for various reasons depending what I try and do. From "The entity or complex type 'SiteTrackerModel.ContactPerson' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query" to other problems. Just have it here to show you what I'm trying in a way.

```
    [BreezeQueryable(MaxExpansionDepth = 3)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<ContactPerson> PersonsFlattened()
    {
        //return _contextProvider.QueryAll<Person>();

        var contacts = from person in _contextProvider.QueryAll<Person>()
                       join companyPerson in CompanyPersons() on person.Id equals companyPerson.PersonId into companyPersonGroups
                       from companyPerson in companyPersonGroups.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new ContactPerson()
                       {
                           FirstName = person.FirstName,
                           IsPrimaryPerson = companyPerson.IsPrimaryPerson,
                           CompanyName = companyPerson.Company.Name
                       };

        return contacts;

    }
```

BreezeJs Call in Angular

```
return EntityQuery.from("PersonsFlattened")
                 //.toType("ContactPerson")
                 .orderBy(orderBy)
                 .using(self.manager).execute()
                 .then(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);
```

Here are the classes/tables I'm trying to flatten and return to breeze. I've trimmed down most of the properties

Person.cs (Person Table in Edmx/db)

```
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Companies = new HashSet<CompanyPerson>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyPerson> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

CompanyPerson.cs (CompanyPerson Table in Edmx/db)

```
public partial class CompanyPerson
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimaryPerson { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Company.cs (Company Table in edmx/db)

```
public partial class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        this.PhoneNumbers = new HashSet<CompanyPhoneNumber>();
        this.Addresses = new HashSet<CompanyAddress>();
        this.Persons = new HashSet<CompanyPerson>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyPerson> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

I even tried creating a view in sql that gave me the data, but I can't get Breezejs to figure out what it is but that was just a means to the goal above. A flattened list of people and companies even if they don't have a company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send projection data to BreezeJS and turn them into a custom `EntityType` you've defined on the client. You can't expect that `ContactPerson` type to show up in metadata from the server that has been generated by Entity Framework; it's a DTO and not part of the model that EF knows about.

That shouldn't stop you from defining `ContactPerson` on your Breeze client. Learn about how to [create client-side metadata](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) in the docs.

> It's worth noting that you **do not have to define all of your metadata on the client** to take advantage of this feature. Just add this `ContactPerson` type.

The next trick is getting BreezeJS to realize that your projection data should be transformed into `ContactPerson` entity on the client.

Breeze won't recognize the anonymous type data by default. You can give it some help with the [`toType` query clause](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_toType). You can uncomment that clause in your query *after you have defined the type in your client metadata*.

```
return EntityQuery.from("PersonsFlattened")
       .toType("ContactPerson") // Should work after defining ContactPerson on client
       .orderBy(orderBy)
       .using(self.manager).execute()
       .then(querySucceeded, self._queryFailed);
```

You won't need the `toType` clause if you project into a server-side `ContactPerson` type and connect the dots between the "PersonsFlattened" endpoint and your custom client-side `ContactPerson` type in metadata. I think I'd rename that endpoint "ContactPersons" for consistency.

**N.B.**: I trust you realize that you've defined read-only types. Breeze doesn't know that so if you make changes to a `ContactPerson` entity in BreezeJS, the manager will try to save it. Your save attempt will throw on the server unless you catch the incoming change on and do something marvelous with it, perhaps in a `BeforeSaveEntity` method.

Comment: Going to try this out this week, will report back to ya. Yes, I did expect it to be read-only.

Answer (score 0):

The exception *"The entity or complex type 'SiteTrackerModel.ContactPerson' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"* is related to how the class `ContactPerson` is declared. LINQ to entity can only construct pur *Data Transfert Object* : class containing only public properties with trivial getter and setter and without constructor.

Check the `ContactPerson` class definition.

Comment: Yup. Need to see how you defined `ContactPerson`. Bet @nlips is correct that the properties are not public. There are examples of this kind of thing in the DocCode sample such as [`ProductDto'](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.Models/ProductDto.cs).